# Paginacion dinamica con PHP

Tags: php, paginación

tengo que realizar un pequeño ajusto en un sitio web, el problema viene en la paginacion.

Por ejemplo tengo una paginacion con 11 botone, estos 1 no los tengo que mostrar de una sola ves, sino que tengo por ejemplo tengo que mostrar los primeros 5 y luego la paginacion se tiene que ir moviendo pero nunca me tiene que dejar de mostrar 5 resultados en la paginacion.

Dejo imágenes de referencia:

Esta es la forma como NO se tiene que ver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma en la que si los debo mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo realizado:

```
                            <ul class="pagination">
                            <?php if ($pagina == 1) : ?>
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <a class="page-link" href="">
                                    <span class="ti-arrow-left"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1 ?>">
                                    <span class="ti-arrow-left"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>


                            <?php
                                for ($i = 1; $i <= $numeroDePaginas; $i++) {
                                    if ($pagina == $i) {
                                        echo "<li class='page-item active'>
                                        <a class='page-link' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a>
                                    </li>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<li class='page-item'>
                                        <a class='page-link' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a>
                                    </li>";
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>

                            <?php if ($pagina == $numeroDePaginas) : ?>
                            <li class='page-item disabled'>
                                <a class='page-link' href=''>
                                    <span class='ti-arrow-right'></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <li class='page-item'>
                                <a class='page-link' href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">
                                    <span class='ti-arrow-right'></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </ul>
```

Comment: Al cargar la página debes mostrar directamente marcado el número 5? y si tienes menos de 5 páginas?

Comment: No, no debo mostrar directamente marcado el 5, la imagen solo fue de ejemplo.

Comment: No era mejor usar [jquery Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) ? El campo `numbers` hace eso.

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas mostrar una determinada cantidad de "Numeración de pagina", te presento una solución donde estableces la cantidad de numeración hacia atrás y hacia adelante:

```
<?php
        $primera= ($pagina - 2) > 1 ? $pagina - 2 : 1;
        $ultima= ($pagina + 2) < $numeroDePaginas ? $pagina + 2 : $numeroDePaginas;
        for ($i = $primera; $i <= $ultima; $i++) {
            echo '<li ><a class="'.( $pagina==$i ? 'active': '').'" href="?pagina=$i">'.$i.'</a></li>';

        }
    ?>
```

- **$primera:** Representa desde donde comienza la numeración teniendo como valor 2 menos a la pagina actual o la numero 1.
- **$ultima:** Representa hasta donde llega la numeración teniendo como valor 2 mas a la pagina actual o en el máximo de paginas.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarias controlar las posiciones que están por encima y por debajo de tu $pagina, con un if puedes solucionarlo:

```js
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numeroDePaginas; $i++) {
  if ($pagina == $i) {
      echo "<li class='page-item active'>
      <a class='page-link' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a>
  </li>";
  } else {
    if(($i+2) == $pagina || ($i-2) == $pagina){
      echo "<li class='page-item'>
      <a class='page-link' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a>
    }
  </li>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Si pero tu codigo de todas formas en un comienzo me sigue mostrando los 11 botones, esto no tendria que pasar.

Comment: Editado, básicamente $i si es 3, y $pagina 5, si está en uno de los dos rangos del if, podrá escribir el <li>, sino no hará nada